# Filter on the Many side of a One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I've got two tables: jobs and job_industries (joined on `jobs.id=job_industries.job_id`).
I'd like to find every job with `jobs.title like '%Finance%'` and without `job_industries.industry=1`.

However, when running the query below, I'm getting a list of every job that matches the title criteria and has at least one industry option that isn't `1`.

```
select jobs.id, title, industry
from `job_industries`
left join jobs on jobs.id=`job_industries`.job_id
where is_live=1 and jobs.`is_closed`=0 and 1 in (select industry from job_industries where job_id in )
```

e.g. if a job has two job_industry relations (`industry=1` and `industry=2`), then this job will match the query. I'd prefer to find jobs that don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, ji.industry
    FROM jobs j
        INNER JOIN job_industries ji
            ON j.id = ji.job_id
                AND ji.industry <> 1
    WHERE j.title LIKE '%Finance%'
        AND j.is_live = 1
        AND j.is_closed = 0
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM job_industries ji2
                            WHERE ji2.job_id = j.id
                                AND ji2.industry = 1);
```

Alternatively, you could do this instead:

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, ji.industry
    FROM jobs j
        INNER JOIN job_industries ji
            ON j.id = ji.job_id
                AND ji.industry <> 1
        LEFT JOIN job_industries ji2
            ON j.id = ji2.job_id
                AND ji2.industry = 1
    WHERE j.title LIKE '%Finance%'
        AND j.is_live = 1
        AND j.is_closed = 0
        AND ji2.job_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: only one correction i /think/ you should make. you're using - instead of =. I converted to = and it seems to work well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select jobs.id, title, industry
from `job_industries`
left join jobs on jobs.id=`job_industries`.job_id AND job_industries.industry=1
where is_live=1 and jobs.`is_closed`=0 and job_industries.industry IS NULL
```